# In the Haskell `System.Console.GetOpt` module, when are option explanations used?

Tags: haskell

I have a question about the [`System.Console.GetOpt`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/System-Console-GetOpt.html) module in the `base` package.

The `OptDescr` data type has a field for a `String` explanation of the command line option.

Where is there ever an opportunity to use this field? Idiomatic Haskell uses a list of options passed into `getOpt`. This means there is no way to access the option from the list in O(1) time. You'd have to iterate through the list to find the option you want. The returned tuple doen't include the explanations. This suggests that the explanations are never used.

All I can think of is that the explanations would appear in error messages, but I shouldn't have to use trial and error to determine this myself. The documentation only uses the word "explanation" once, and does not have an... explanation of what the explanations are used for.

```
data OptDescr a

    Each OptDescr describes a single option.
    The arguments to Option are:

        - list of short option characters
        - list of long option strings (without "--")
        - argument descriptor
        - explanation of option for user

    Constructors:

        Option [Char] [String] (ArgDescr a) String
```

Comment: ...I don't think a *rudimentary options parser* cares about list access being not O(1).

Comment: I don‘t think I want to see the application that is weird enough for Option parsing performance to be a major concern

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are printed when you call [`usageInfo`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/System-Console-GetOpt.html#v:usageInfo) with the same list of options.

Comment: You may also want to check the error messages produced by `getOpt`